# Rally Excel Plugin Queries

Tags: sql, excel, rally

I am working with the Rally/Excel plug-in and setting up queries/filters for our various delivery teams.  One of the teams is named "Agency / L&C".  The & is causing me all sorts of problems that I cannot seem to get past.  The current filter is: 
    ((Release.Name = "2013 November") AND (Project.Name = "Agency / L&C"))
When I execute the query I get this error:
    Query failed due to errors:
    Could not parse:  Cannot parse expression "((Release.Name = "2013 November") AND        (Project.Name = "Agency / L" as a query

I have tried several things, ' before and after, '' before and after, %, " and \ and nothing seems to be making it register the & as text.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an educated guess but I would think the problem arises from the ampersand not being escaped before the request is made to the to the API. You might try changing it to "%26" (the HTML code for "&") and see what you get.

Comment: My thanks that worked!  The irony here is I even tried the ASCI for & earlier and failed.  Much appreciated.